# Install non-product version of Fedora from scratch?

Tags: fedora, system-installation

As of Fedora 21, Fedora now has three versions, which it calls "products": the Workstation product, the Server product, and the Cloud product.  When you download a Live DVD or other installation medium, you need to decide which of these three products you want.

However, in practice there's actually a fourth kind of product: non-product ("nonproduct").  Fedora advises that if you want to install Fedora on a workstation but use a desktop other than GNOME, that you should do a non-product install.

How do I do a non-product installation of Fedora 21 or later?  Is ther a way to do it?  What installation media should I use?

I'm not asking how to upgrade from Fedora 20 to Fedora 21 (I already know how to do that); I'm asking about a clean, fresh install on a new empty hard disk.

Comment: 1. [This bug listing](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F21_bugs#environment-product-conflicts) mentions a non-product install, but doesn't say how to do it.  2. What I really want to achieve: install the MATE desktop, without Compiz (without using the MATE+Compiz spin) -- but I thought ask the more general question, in hopes answers are more broadly useful to others.

Comment: Just use which ever one and install whatever desktop you want and remove whatever desktop you don't want.  **The repository is the same in any case.**  It doesn't matter.  You are best off starting from the workstation install.  It does not mean you have to use whatever the default DE is.

Comment: @goldilocks, Are you sure that is possible?  [The bug report](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F21_bugs#environment-product-conflicts) says that won't work: it says you can't switch from product (say Workstation) to non-product after installation.

Comment: That's not what that bug report says (and it also states "there is a simple workaround" to the very minor sounding issue that it does describe). But let's assume its true anyway -- because TBH, I would not switch from "cloud" to "workstation", etc. without expecting some screw-ups, and in fact, I would not expect *or desire* an easy means of doing so, because **it doesn't matter**.  You can't switch your "cloud" install wholesale over to a "server" install. So what? Who cares?  Again: It doesn't matter...

Comment: **These are just very high level, abstract macro categories** (as are the "environment groups" in the bug report).  This isn't going to stop you from installing or removing anything.  If I had installed "Workstation" and I wanted to run a server with it, *I would just install the appropriate software*.  Likewise, if I had installed "Server" and wanted a GUI desktop, I'd just install the appropriate software...

Comment: ...If you want to use KDE or MATE instead of GNOME, install KDE or MATE and make the appropriate configuration changes.  The categories are just there to simplify life if you have a good idea of what you want to do to start with.  **They are NOT going to prevent you from doing anything you can do on any other F21 install.**  Likewise, those grouplists are macropackages designed to facilitate forms of organization that would be simple to enough to organize yourself (and again, there's a workaround listed) when you know you need to.

Comment: Might there be glitches for somebody somewhere with something?  Sure, of course there will.  But there is not going to be a mechanism there which when you try to install MATE on a "Server" box says, "Nope, sorry, not allowed -- you said three months ago you wanted a headless server, it is too late to change your mind now".  That would be totally absurd and it is not the way fedora, or any other distro I'm aware of, works.  That said, if you want the most correct way to get a fresh, MATE oriented install using the "non-product" mechanism, I don't know (which is why I don't have an answer).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to install from a netinstall iso image for server (supposing it works the same with any other installation medium):

- Choose the `minimal install` in `software selection` window, and install the os.
- If it is fedora 21, install the package `system-release-nonproduct` on yum command line which actually will install `fedora-release-nonproduct` package.
- If it is fedora 22, there is not a `nonproduct` package. As long as it does not install `fedora-release-server`, `fedora-release-cloud`, `fecora-release-workstation`, it's all set.

The the product package name prefix `system-release-` is actually converted to `fedora-release-` by `yum`/`dnf`. Knowing that, you can just use the actual package name to manage the product. Let's say, if you want to remove a product, just remove all the packages associated with the product package (getting them from the yum history). Then you can install another product.

Inside the `nonproduct` package for fedora 21, there is only one license file at `/usr/share/licenses/fedora-release-nonproduct/LICENSE`. Installing the package actually only prevents you from installing other products.

Comment: To the specific MATE question: If installing fedora 22, just select `MATE Desktop` in place of the `Minimal Install`. Check with `dnf` to make sure none of the products is installed.